# Populating multiple blocks from a block when clicking on a button in Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, oracleforms

Hi I am having a problem when populating data to other blocks. The PatientInformation block only gets populated and the other one is not.
Here's the code when clicking on the button

```
DECLARE 
    x VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

x := 'IDNumber =' || chr(39) || :patientinformation.searchbyid || chr(39);

set_block_property('PATIENTINFORMATION', default_where, x);
set_block_property('HOSPITAL', default_where, x);
execute_query(all_records);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXECUTE_QUERY` queries resords only in current block. `ALL_RECORDS` parameter instructs forms to select all rows from table, not only the first set.

If you need to populate more blocks, you have to navigate to each and execute query, like this

```
DECLARE 
    x VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

    x := 'IDNumber =' || chr(39) || :patientinformation.searchbyid || chr(39);

    set_block_property('PATIENTINFORMATION', default_where, x);
    set_block_property('HOSPITAL', default_where, x);

    go_block('PATIENTINFORMATION');
    execute_query;
    go_block('HOSPITAL');
    execute_query;

END;
```